# Is it possible to create interfaces for Typed Dataset table row field values?

Tags: c#, interface, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a couple of tables in a typed dataset that share some common fields.  I created an interface for these fields, and added it to the table rows with partial classes.  Everything compiles, but it does not work when I try to use it with the interface.

I read somewhere that the implementation of the interface needs to be in the same partial class.  This kind of sucks, if this is true they should make the compiler complain.

Has anyone else run into this?  Any workarounds?

Here is my code

First the interface:

```
public interface IDataField
{
    //These two fields are generated in the typed data tables
    string Data_Field_Name { get; set; }

    int Data_Field_ID { get; set; }

}
```

Now the fields are generated in the typed dataset, by the data set designer, and all that, and I am sure the properties exists so I add the interface to the partial class file I created. This class will compile fine, it likes the interface so far.

```
public partial class Data
{
    public partial class Data_FieldRow:IDataField
    {
    }
}
```

Now I add a method to use the interface:

```
public static void PopulateFieldDropdown(DropDownList ddlFields
            , IEnumerable<IDataField> Fields
            , string SelectedValue
            , bool AddBlank
            , string LanguageCode)
```

Everything compiles up to this point.
Now when I try to call it

```
using (DataTableAdapters.Data_FieldTableAdapter a = new DataTableAdapters.Data_FieldTableAdapter())
{  
    Data.Data_FieldDataTable dataFieldTable = a.GetData();
    globals.ui.PopulateFieldDropdown(ddlFields, dataFieldTable, null, true, globals.LanguageCode);
}
```

I get the error

```
Argument '2': cannot convert from 'Data.Data_FieldDataTable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IDataField>
```

**Solution:**
Apparently you cannot just pass in an IEnumerable collection of something that implements an interface, you have to actually cast all the items in the collection.

So in the method call I had to change **dataFieldTable**  to **dataFieldTable.ToList().ConvertAll(c => (IDataField)c)**

**Thanks Ian Ringrose for verifying that interfaces DO work on generated row field values.**
Thanks Ian!!

Comment: I have had this work OK for me, please post a **short** bit of code that shows what you are doing.

Comment: You are right Ian it does work.  If you post a short answer I will mark you as answer if you like for verifying that it does work.

Although why the compiler cannot figure out the IEnumerable collection without casting everything inside does not make sense to me.  I guess I still have a lot to learn about interfaces.

Comment: You must be using a version of .NET prior to 4.0. Starting with 4.0, some generic interfaces support a feature called **covariance**, which would allow you to treat an `IEnumerable<FieldRow>` as an `IEnumerable<IDataField>`. Google "covariance .NET generics" (or something like that) and you should find some helpful resources on this topic.